# Merge two dictionaries

Tags: javascript, hash-map, ecmascript-6

This function merges two dictionaries, using the value from the later dictionary to resolve conflicts.

I have 5 tests that the program passes successfully:

```
const cases = [
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'uno' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'due' }], { a: 'due', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, {}], { a: 'uno' }],
];
```

How can I improve this code?

```
const objects = (first, second) => {
 const object = {};
  for (item of Object.keys(first)) {
    object[item] = first[item];
  }
  for (item of Object.keys(second)) {
    object[item] = second[item];
  }
  return object;
};
```

Comment: Seems like there are better ways: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Spread syntax exists to solve this problem already

Answer (score 6):

## Function name could be improved

The name `objects` is not very descriptive of what the function does. One reading the code could get confused and think `objects` was an array of objects. A more descriptive name might be *mergeObjects*, *mergeDictionaries*, etc.

## Simplifying the function

As was mentioned in a comment [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) could be used to simplify the function. Note that if more complex dictionaries are needed - e.g. if using values other than primitives like nested objects or arrays, this may not work as expected:

> For [deep cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy), we need to use alternatives, because `Object.assign()` copies property values.
> <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone)</sup>

```js
const cases = [
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'uno' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'due' }], { a: 'due', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, {}], { a: 'uno' }],
];
const mergeObjects = (first, second) => Object.assign(first, second);

for (const caseEntry of cases) console.log(JSON.stringify(caseEntry[1]) ===  JSON.stringify(mergeObjects(...caseEntry[0])) ? 
'✅' : '❌')
```

And utilizing the ES-6 feature [Spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) it can be simplified so the call to the `assign` method is eliminated:

```js
const cases = [
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'uno' }], { a: 'uno', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno', b: 'due' }, { a: 'due' }], { a: 'due', b: 'due' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, { c: 'tre' }], { a: 'uno', c: 'tre' }],
  [[{ a: 'uno' }, {}], { a: 'uno' }],
];
const mergeObjects = (first, second) => ({...first, ...second});

for (const caseEntry of cases) console.log(JSON.stringify(caseEntry[1]) ===  JSON.stringify(mergeObjects(...caseEntry[0])) ? 
'✅' : '❌')
```